# How can I get disk access log on win10?

Tags: windows-10

The resource monitor is good. It lists the accessed resources and who accessed them. But it's realtime, and I can't collect data over a period of time.

On the other hand, the performance monitor provides such a way but without access detail.

Is there any way to get a disk access log (with accessed resources and corresponding processes)? It would be better if the tool is win10 built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process Monitor can create a persistent log of all disk access events, with detailed information on the type and path of access, the processes involved, the user credentials of the process, and much more.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Answer (score 2):

You can use Event Viewer to see who last accessed a file and possibly other resources

https://smallbusiness.chron.com/see-accessed-file-last-network-66995.html

You will have to turn Auditing on first and let this information collect and then get an event viewer filter to distill the information

Quote from the article above

> 1. Press "Windows-Q," type "secpol.msc" into the search field, and then press "Enter" to open Local Security Policy.
> 2. Expand "Security Settings" and "Local Policies," and then click the "Audit Policy" folder.
> 3. Double-click "Audit Object Access" in the right pane to open the Audit Object Access Properties dialog box.
> 4. Check "Define These Policy Settings," check "Success," and then click "OK" to monitor file access.
> 5. Press "Windows-E" to open File Explorer, navigate to the appropriate folder, right-click the target file and select "Properties" from the context menu, and then click "Security."
> 6. Click the "Advanced" button, click the "Auditing" tab, and then click "Continue." Click the "Add" button, and then click the "Select a Principal" link.
> 7. Type the name of a user or group into the available field, click "Check Names," and then click "OK."
> 8. Select "Success" from the "Type" drop-down menu, select the appropriate permissions for the user or group, and then click "OK."